# MySQL Refusing Remote Connections

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mariadb

Using: 
MySQL/MariaDB Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23
Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab131.1 x86_64)

Everything works perfectly from the local machine (a remote dedicated server) such as PYPMyAdmin, SQLAlchemy, etc, but it will not accept any remote connections. I can telnet to the MySQL port, it gives me a login prompt, and I have already set the remote user up with:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'p4$$w0rd' WITH GRANT OPTION;
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

And yet I still get the following error when I try to login remotely via Python/SQLAlchemy. "Access denied for user 'admin'@'myrdns.myisp.net"

Is there some additional security feature that I need to tweak that I am unaware of to enable remote access to one server from another?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change/add grants for your desired username in order to access your database remotely, i.e.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

You'll need to issue the following command as well, before being able to connect.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Since you (probably) did it already, you might wish to check your config file, in order to see if there's any bind address being set. In case of editing your config file, you'll need to issue server restart.

Sometimes it's due to some firewall blocking rules as well, but you'll need to confirm and resolve it on your network/machine if that's the case.

Be warned, however, that it is advised that you set up SSL certificate if you allow remote access to your database.
Also be aware that you can issue remote login without logging in "directly", i.e. you can connect to your remote machine/server via **SSH client**, then connect to your mysql server via `localhost/127.0.0.1` address.

Comment: That didn't work for me. Same error. And the bind address appears to be correct. As mentioned, I can see the server remotely, it just won't let my client login.

Comment: Copy/pasting one of locally-accessible instances on a linux dedicated server: 
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1 <--------- try to find and comment this part, if you have it. it's located in my.cnf configuration file. You'll need to restart your mysql server afterwards.

Comment: I don't see a bind-address anywhere in my configuration files, not mysqld.cnf , mysql.conf, or my.cnf. However, in my Webmin MySQL Manager it is set to accept connections from All Hosts, and again, I can see the MySQL login when I telnet to port 3306 from the remote client. It's listening on port 3306 ont he right IP, it just won't accept remote logins.